# encountering a problem when trying to scrape

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Hi I am just starting to learn some coding via tutorials and started practicing but getting an error when trying to run a test. please see my code below. Hoping to get some help.

The following is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
req = Request('https://www.niche.com/k12/search/best-schools/s/arkansas/?gradeLevel=middle&gradeLevel=high&type=traditional&type=charter&type=magnet&type=private', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
req.close()
page_soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")
card = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"card"})

csv_file = open('headmasters_scrape.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['School', 'Niche_Grade', 'School_Type'])

for cards in card:
    Item_1 = cards.findAll("h2", {"class":"search-result__title"})
    School = Item_1[0].text
    Item_2 = cards.findAll("figure", {"class":"search-result-grade"})
    Niche_Grade = Item_2[0].text
    Item_3 = cards.findAll("li", {"class":"search-result-tagline__item"})
    School_Type = Item_3[0].text

    print("School: " + School)
    print("Niche_Grade: " + Niche_Grade)
    print("School_Type: " + School_Type)    

    print()

    csv_writer.writerow([School, Niche_Grade, School_Type])

    csv_file.close()
```

The error that I'm getting is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Amdin\Downloads\Webscrape\Edited_Version.py", line 4, in 
<module>
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
File "C:\Users\Amdin\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in 
urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Users\Amdin\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "C:\Users\Amdin\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 548, in 
_open
'unknown_open', req)
File "C:\Users\Amdin\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in 
_call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Users\Amdin\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1387, in 
unknown_open
raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

Comment: can you share the entire traceback

Comment: Hi edited my question and indicated the complete traceback. Thanks!

Comment: what do you get for the following code: `import requests requests.get(url)`, url must be your url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0'}
r = requests.get("https://www.niche.com/k12/search/best-schools/s/arkansas/?gradeLevel=middle&gradeLevel=high&type=traditional&type=charter&type=magnet&type=private", headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

name = []
grade = []
sctype = []
for item in soup.findAll("h2", {'class': 'search-result__title'}):
    name.append(item.text)
for item in soup.select("div[class^=niche__grade]"):
    grade.append(item.text)
for item in soup.findAll("ul", {'class': 'search-result-tagline'}):
    sctype.append(item.next_element.text)

data = []
for a, b, c in zip(name, grade, sctype):
    lol = a, b, c
    data.append(lol)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["School", "Niche_Grade", "School_Type"])

df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Output: [check online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/87d2e588313c81e75b565a1b330330cc/data.csv)
[image]

Comment: thank you Ahmed, this is great. Is it possible to loop in all the pages?

Comment: @Ann you can `loop` over the pages by appending the following parameter `page=` to the end of the url. and loop over it using `for item in range(1, 27)`

Comment: @ahmed I did but I got this error:  f = open(path_or_buf, mode, encoding=encoding, newline="")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'data.csv'

Comment: I was able to resolve the error, my only problem is after modifying the loop its still getting the first page only

Comment: @Ann for that, you will need to open a separate question as you have received the answer for the question which you described above.

Comment: oh I see. I'll post another one then. Thanks for helping @ahmed